# Selenium - Automate 'Upload an image/file' functionality that works on both Windows and Linux

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate uploading an image functionality. It is working in Windows in my local using Robotclass. Our Jenkins use Linux and it's not working on Linux OS.

I tried both AutoIT and Robotclass. Looking for a solution that helps automating upload an image/file that works on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: you shouldn't need robot class... you can send keys of the path to the file to the <input type="file"> element and then submit the form.